# Completion for the first argument of cd OLD NEW

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, cd-command

In `zsh`, the `cd` command has a two-argument form: `cd OLD NEW` changes to `${PWD/OLD/NEW}`. With the new-style completion system, zsh is capable of completing `NEW`: the second argument is completed based on what `OLD` can be substituted with to obtain an existing directory. But the first argument is only completed to existing directories.

How can I get zsh to offer completions that are possible values for `OLD`, in addition to completing existing directories?

For example, if the current directory is `/path/to/foo` and there are also directories `/also/to/foo` and `/path/to/foo/prime`, then `cd p`<kbd>Tab</kbd> completes `p` to `prime`. If I intend to run `cd path also` then I'd like zsh to also offer `path` as a completion. How?

Using already-typed values of the second argument to limit the possibilities for the first argument would be a plus, but completing the first argument independently would be fine too.

Comment: Would your 2-argument completion example be: `cd p also <Tab>`, or `cd p also <left arrow x 5> <Tab>`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller The second-argument-sensitive example would be `cd p also<Left*5><Tab>`: if I press `<Tab>` while the cursor is in `also`, I expect `also` to be completed, not `p`.

Comment: If you type `cd t<tab>` should it offer `th/to/foo/prime` and `to/foo/prime`? Or should it just limit itself to directory boundaries?

Comment: @Barmar I think limiting to directory boundaries would be the most convenient.

Comment: INteresting question...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could add the components of `$PWD` to the `cd` completion list, though this appears to require fiddling with `_cd`; that is, a customized version of `_cd` must appear first in `$fpath`.

```
% cd && mkdir zcomp
% cp $fpath[-1]/_cd zcomp
% fpath=(~/zcomp $fapth)
```

Then up at the top of `~/zcomp/_cd` add a function

```
_our_pwd() {
  _values ourpwd ${(ps:/:)PWD}
}
```

and then just before the `_alternative` line add what that returns to the list of alternatives

```
  ...
  alt=("$service-options:$service option:_cd_options" "$alt[@]")
fi

alt=(ourpwd:pwd:_our_pwd "$alt[@]")

_alternative "$alt[@]" && ret=0

return ret
...
```

though this will always add the `pwd` components to `cd` completions:

```
% cd
Users    jdoe    Applications/  Desktop/  Documents/  Downloads/  Library/
...
```

with additional logic you could only add the `$PWD` components when there is already a second argument present instead of always.

However! This always messes up the `cd` completion and requires that we monkey patch the upstream `_cd` completion. Another option would be to create a new name for the function provided by the two-arg `cd`, perhaps called `cdsub`, and only have the completion of `PWD` components appear for that. Add this to `~/.zshrc`

```
function cdsub { builtin cd "$@" }
```

And then a gutted `_cd` [completion for `_cdsub`](https://github.com/thrig/zsh-compdef/blob/master/_cdsub) to be placed somewhere in `$fpath`:

```
#compdef cdsub
#
# Modified version of _cd from ZSH 5.3.1 with specific support for the
# `cd old new` form whereby PWD elements are provided for completion.

_cd_options() {
  _arguments -s \
  '-q[quiet, no output or use of hooks]' \
  '-s[refuse to use paths with symlinks]' \
  '(-P)-L[retain symbolic links ignoring CHASE_LINKS]' \
  '(-L)-P[resolve symbolic links as CHASE_LINKS]'
}

setopt localoptions nonomatch

local expl ret=1 curarg
integer argstart=2 noopts

if (( CURRENT > 1 )); then
  # if not in command position, may have options.
  # Careful: -<-> is not an option.
  while [[ $words[$argstart] = -* && argstart -lt CURRENT ]]; do
    curarg=$words[$argstart]
    [[ $curarg = -<-> ]] && break
    (( argstart++ ))
    [[ $curarg = -- ]] && noopts=1 && break
  done
fi

if [[ CURRENT -eq $((argstart+1)) ]]; then
  # cd old new: look for old in $PWD and see what can replace it
  local rep
  # Get possible completions using word in position 2
  rep=(${~PWD/$words[$argstart]/*}~$PWD(-/))
  # Now remove all the common parts of $PWD and the completions from this
  rep=(${${rep#${PWD%%$words[$argstart]*}}%${PWD#*$words[$argstart]}})
  (( $#rep )) && _wanted -C replacement strings expl replacement compadd -a rep
else
  _values ourpwd ${(ps:/:)PWD} && ret=0
  return ret
fi
```