# Best way to browse different versions of a backup of a directory

Tags: zsh, backup

I am using a rsync backup script (see here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29429/push-backup-script) which creates directories like

`back-2015-07-02T21_18_01`

Now suppose I am in commandline (`zsh`) on `/path/to/my/backup/back-2015-07-02T21_18_01/home/myuser/myfiles/somedir/subdir/` and I want to switch to `/path/to/my/backup/back-2016-04-02T21_17_01/home/myuser/myfiles/somedir/subdir/`.

What's the fastest/best way to do this in `zsh`? I usually use zsh menu completion, so it would be great if I could just choose via menu tab completion another date but keep the current subdir (just from the other backup date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to be pragmatic, and since writing a zsh completion is outside my current skills, I'd just write a special purpose function using the `select` menu system from zsh (and bash).

```
cdd(){
    typeset dir
    typeset -a dirs
    if [[ $PWD =~ ^(.*)(/back-[0-9-]+T[0-9_]+/)(.*)$ ]]
    then    for dir in "$match[1]"/*/"$match[3]"
            do      [ "$dir" != "$PWD"  -a  -d "$dir" ] && dirs+=("$dir")
            done
            select dir in "$dirs[@]"
            do      echo "$dir"
                    cd "$dir"
                    break
            done
    else    echo "no date in $PWD"
    fi
}
```

This splits the current directory into three parts around the directory with a date pattern, and then replaces that with a glob `*`. The resulting list is presented by zsh with a `1) ... 2) ...` style menu where you just enter 1 or 2 to cd to that directory.

Answer (score 3):

One way to exchange one directory component for another in `zsh` is the two-argument version of `cd`:

```sh
cd old new
```

This substitutes `new` for the first substring matching `old` and tries to change directory to the resulting path. For example:

```sh
% pwd
/path/to/my/backup/back-2015-07-02T21_18_01/home/myuser/myfiles/somedir/subdir/
% cd "5-07-02T21_18_01" "6-04-02T21_17_01"
/path/to/my/backup/back-2016-04-02T21_17_01/home/myuser/myfiles/somedir/subdir/
% pwd
/path/to/my/backup/back-2016-04-02T21_17_01/home/myuser/myfiles/somedir/subdir/
```

Search and replace is done entirely on a string level and replacement is always done only on the first match. So if you are in `/foo/foo/foo/foo`, running `cd foo bar` will always try to change directory to `/bar/foo/foo/foo`, whether it actually exists or not. It will not go looking for an alternative like `/foo/foo/bar/foo`, even should it exist.

Completion for the second argument is provided by `compinit`, but you have to type the first argument (at least with default completion settings). Should `compinit` - for some reason - not be enabled, you can change that by running `autoload -U compinit; compinit` (and adding it to your `~/.zshrc`).

**Note**: `cd` supports `/` characters in the `old` and new string, meaning you can switch from `/a/b/c/d` to `/x/y/z/c/d` by running `cd a/b x/y/z`. But it seems that completion does not work in that case, so you have to type the second argument by yourself, too.

Comment: For completion of OLD, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282396/completion-for-the-first-argument-of-cd-old-new (currently unanswered).